# The PreferredDevice for the AudioRecord dose not use every time

Tags: java, android

I record audio with `AudioRecord` and play it with `AudioTrack`.
I can choose the input and output device(mobile phone, bluetooth device).
The Input and output are running at the same time.

For the output over `AudioTrack` it works, but for the input over `AudioRecord` it only works once.

> e.g. when I use the mobile phone for the input device. Start and stop
>   the record. And than use a other device (bluetooth device). If I start
>   the record the mobile phone is still the input device.

I use the audio source `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`.
I set the preferred Device with `audioRecord.setPreferredDevide(audioDeviceInfo`).
The return is true.

Every time when I start the process it will be create a new audioRecord and audioTrack object.

The new input devices should be used, not the first device